# Tensorflow on macOS Apple M1

Tags: macos, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensor flow on my macOS M1.
As per chip compatibility I know that not all the pip images of tensor flow works or are even compatible. But I found this repository

https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos

Which is supposed to be working on Apple M1.

After the installation, I downgraded my python to version 3.8 and start the installation, everything went just fine without any issue.

just for testing purpose, I found this script online.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# ## Sentiment Analysis on US Airline Reviews

# In[1]:


import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from tensorflow.python.compiler.mlcompute import mlcompute
mlcompute.set_mlc_device(device_name='cpu')
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM,Dense, Dropout, SpatialDropout1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding


df = pd.read_csv("./Tweets.csv")


# In[2]:


df.head()


# In[23]:


df.columns


# In[4]:


tweet_df = df[['text','airline_sentiment']]
print(tweet_df.shape)
tweet_df.head(5)


# In[22]:


tweet_df = tweet_df[tweet_df['airline_sentiment'] != 'neutral']
print(tweet_df.shape)
tweet_df.head(5)


# In[21]:


tweet_df["airline_sentiment"].value_counts()


# In[6]:


sentiment_label = tweet_df.airline_sentiment.factorize()
sentiment_label


# In[7]:


tweet = tweet_df.text.values
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(tweet)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(tweet)
padded_sequence = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=200)


# In[8]:


print(tokenizer.word_index)


# In[9]:


print(tweet[0])
print(encoded_docs[0])


# In[10]:


print(padded_sequence[0])


# In[11]:


embedding_vector_length = 32
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_vector_length, input_length=200) )
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])  
print(model.summary()) 


# In[12]:


history = model.fit(padded_sequence,sentiment_label[0],validation_split=0.2, epochs=5, batch_size=32)


# In[16]:


plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='acc')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='val_acc')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig("Accuracy plot.jpg")


# In[25]:


plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='val_loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig("Loss plot.jpg")


# In[18]:


def predict_sentiment(text):
    tw = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])
    tw = pad_sequences(tw,maxlen=200)
    prediction = int(model.predict(tw).round().item())
    print("Predicted label: ", sentiment_label[1][prediction])


# In[19]:


test_sentence1 = "I enjoyed my journey on this flight."
predict_sentiment(test_sentence1)

test_sentence2 = "This is the worst flight experience of my life!"
predict_sentiment(test_sentence2)
```

But when I run it,

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sentiment Analysis.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.compiler.mlcompute import mlcompute
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

The error is about the architecture but I have no idea how to fix. Did anyone found a solution to this problem?

Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you tried suggestions discussed [here](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/146), [here](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/21)?

Answer (score 2):

Things should work better now.

As of Oct. 25, 2021 macOS 12 Monterey is [generally available](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/10/macos-monterey-is-now-available/).

Upgrade your machine to Monterey or newer OS if you haven't already.

If you have conda installed, I would probably uninstall it. You can have multiple conda versions installed but things can get tricky.

Then follow the instructions from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/). I cleaned them up a bit below:

Download and install Conda from Miniforge:

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate
```

In an active conda environment, install the TensorFlow dependencies, base TensorFlow, and TensorFlow metal:

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
pip install tensorflow-macos
pip install tensorflow-metal
```

You should be good to go with fast training speeds.

Comment: *"If you have conda installed, uninstall it."* - that's a bit much. I'm a Miniforge/Mambaforge fan, but uprooting an existing installation is unnecessary.

Comment: To clarify, I am not recommending multiple installations. One can toggle an installation between architectures by setting the `subdir` configuration value (**osx-64** vs **osx-arm64**).  This can even be done on a per environment basis.