# Unable to install tensorflow with pip in virtualenv

Tags: tensorflow, pip

facing below error while installing tensorflow

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

pip version and python version

```
pip 22.2.2 
python 3.10
```

Comment: Which commands are you running to install tensorflow?

Comment: Not only commands but the platform as well.

Comment: Hi @akash, please let us know the Tensorflow version and the platform on which you are trying to install it so that we can assist you better. Kindly refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72970797/14290697). Thank you!