# R Package Conflicts in Anaconda3

Tags: r, anaconda, conda

I have installed Anaconda 3 for Mac M1 and I am trying to create a new environment for R. However, everytime I try to do this, I am faced with the below error:

[Conda Prompt Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuTt9.png)

I am faced with this error irrespective of whether I try to do this in anaconda navigator or conda prompt. I have already tried removing Anaconda completely and reinstalling it again but to no avail. Is there anything I can do here?

Update: As requested, here is an additional screenshot:
[Mamba install r-eesentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brxy7.png)

[Mamba install r-essentials output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoZyd.png)

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of text and shell outputs. Also, please indicate what is already in the environment - solving install requests is context-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

**[Disclosure: I am a volunteer on the Conda Forge R team.]**

Conda users who want to use R should prioritize [Conda Forge](https://conda-forge.org/#about). The Anaconda company has not actively maintained R packages since v3.6.

If installing Conda for the first time, I recommend [Miniforge variants](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) (specifically, Mambaforge), rather than the Anaconda distributions (which prioritize **defaults**/**anaconda** channel).

Also note that **osx-arm64** support for R through Conda is currently sparse. We are actively working on migrating, but for simplicity of workflow, I still recommend Conda users to install a **osx-64** version of Conda and use that platform when installing R. You can always create native **osx-arm64** environments when you actually need them (e.g., [native TensorFlow with Metal support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72970797/570918)).

Comment: I have installed Mambaforge as suggested by you. I created a new environment using mambaforge.  I then installed r-base 4.2.1 with mamba install and conda-forge                                                                                                         
However, I am facing the below error while installing r-essentials with mamba and conda-forge: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides r-base >=3.5.1,<3.5.2.0a0 needed by r-essentials-3.5.1-r351_2000.

Comment: Please add a section to the original question to show what you did. It would help to see the output of `mamba list` for the environment - the message indicated is not enough info with which to diagnose.

Comment: As requested, I have added additional screenshots. Please note them in my original question.