# using https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691304 to try to integrate Mac M1 gpu into tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

My constant problem is that I am using the apple recommended way to get 'Get started with tensorflow-metal'. My problem is always in the same place no matter which method I try- I have the same problem:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- tensorflow-deps

I can't seem to get arounf this despite using Anaconda 2022.3.1. Can someone suggest a way to get around this? Or can someone suggest a completely new starting point

Comment: Could you check with miniconda version mentioned in metal plugin document and install tensorflow-deps through below command and let us know.  [Ref](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)

Comment: Hi @Christopher Gaughan, Could you please refer to this [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) official link to instal tensorflow in your system using conda? or can refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76289118/21904865). You can use code `python -m pip install tensorflow-metal` for the tensorflow-gpu . Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.