# Python Kernel Restarting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Importing the **keras** and **tersorflow** on my jupyter notebook always forces my Kernel to die and restart. Both these packages never get imported successfully. But they used to work before. What could be causing this problem now?

I uninstalled  the packages, and reinstalled them afresh, this did not solve the problem.

I CREATED A NEW ENVIRONMENT AND INSTALLED THE PACKAGES THERE, STILL SAME ISSUE PERSISTED.

I have rebooted the computer so many times, thinking its a memomy issue, still no changes.

Comment: What happens when you import those packages outside of a notebook? Do you get a specific error message? Are you using a GPU, and if so, what drivers are you using and can you communicate with it outside of those packages (`nvidia-smi`?)?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT AT US.

Comment: @Brian61354270 I am using the MacBook Air, with the GPU that comes standard. When I run the code from the terminal command, I get this error, "zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python example.py"

Comment: Hi @Shawn Pilusa, Please refer to this [TF Install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) official link to install tensorflow by following all the step by step instructions mentioned. You can also refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76289118/21904865) which might be helpful. Please let us know if the issue still persists.