# Why is tensorflow not installed despite having installed it

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

I have an Apple Silicon Mac and am trying to install tensor flow that can use the internal GPU/ANE to speed up processing.

I followed all the instructions on the Apple website https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/ but on PyCharm, it still shows that there is no tensor flow installed. Note: when I ran the commands in terminal, none of them returned an error

Answer (score 0):

It seems tensorflow did not get install in your system or there might be a path mismatch of TF installation. Please have a look at this [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) official link and follow the mentioned step by step instructions to install tensorflow in your system. You can also refer this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76289118/21904865) for the reference.

After installing the tensorflow through conda environment, install and and open the pycharm from the same created conda environment. Set the python interpreter
**(Setting - Project Setting - Python Interpreter - Add Interpreter - conda environment - select created conda virtual environment - Ok)**

[image]

Now open a new python file and import the tensorflow to verify its version in Pycharm IDE as below:

[image]