# Install Tensorflow in MacOs M1

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1

I am struggling to install tensorflow on MacOS  Monterey 12.5.1 with M1 Chip

`pip3 install tensorflow-macos`

`pip3 install tensorflow-metal`

I keep getting this error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: none)`

I tried venv, I tried miniconda, anaconda, still same issue.

How can I install tensorflow in M1 MacOS ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way to install TensorFlow on Apple M1 in 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964800/what-is-the-proper-way-to-install-tensorflow-on-apple-m1-in-2022)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow installation instructions from the apple developer [website](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/).
With conda first, you need to install tensorflow-deps with:

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
```

then

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-macOS
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

This is the procedure recommended by apple, so if you haven't installed "tensorflow-deps", first try that.
Also this is suggested for your problem in the same webpage:

> Error: “Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow-macos (from versions: none).” A TensorFlow installation
> wheel that matches the current Python environment couldn’t be found by
> the package manager. Check that the Python version used in the
> environment is supported (Python 3.8, Python 3.9, Python 3.10).

So try using the mentioned Python versions.
Also, [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/686926) is the long thread of people facing different issues with TensorFlow on mac, which helped me a lot.

Comment: It helped. I try to install the package: `python3 -m pip install murre` 
But I get the following error: 

`ERROR: Cannot install murre==1.3.0 and murre==1.4.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.`
So I tried: `python3 -m pip install murre==1.4`
I get: 
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.4.0 (from murre) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.4.0`
Any suggestions?

Comment: Based on murre github you need tensorflow 2.4.0 for it. So first make sure that its the version you have installed.  But I think the tensorflow 2.4 is not released for apple silicon. so either go with CPU version of tensorflow, or try to compile and install murre from source with newer version of tensorflow on apple silicon and wish it works! :D
P.S. : you can find the tf releases for apple silicon https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install python@3.8
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.16/bin/python3.8  -m venv ~/TF
source ~/TF/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow-macos
```