# Jupyter Notebook Kerneal dies

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, error-messaging, jupyter-kernel

I'm a new, novice user of `Jupyter`; having just successfully installed Anaconda, along with some packages I need (`tensorflow` and `keras`), I keep on getting `'the kerneal appears to have died. It will restart automatically'` error message when I try to run this cell:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Other cells before the above cell execute ok.

Error message screenshot:
[image: Error message screenshot]
I'm using an m1 Apple chip.

To resolve the issue I have already tried the following:

> - Refresh the page and try running the code again.
> - Restart the kernel. You can do this by going to the "Kernel" menu and selecting "Restart".
> - If restarting the kernel doesn't work, try shutting down the notebook completely and reopening it.
> - If none of the above steps work, you can try reinstalling Jupyter Notebook or restarting your computer.
> - Check if there is any code that may be causing the kernel to crash, such as an infinite loop or large memory usage. If you suspect this is
>   the case, try modifying your code to avoid these issues.

Comment: This won't help your probable memory issue but going forward you'll have a better experience in modern Jupyter,(not google colab), by using `%pip install` for install commands like you show in your screenshot. The exclamation point in conjunction with install commands can causes issues so the magic `%pip install` and related `%conda install` commands were added to insure installation occurs in the environment being used by the kernel underlying the notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more ...

Comment: <continued>  the modern magic install commands. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for why it is best to avoid exclamation point with install commands. Plus, keep in mind because you are using the Anaconda/conda system as your package manager, **you should always preferably be using `conda` to handle your installs going forward**. For best robustness and portability of your environments, only fall back to using `pip` in cases for where a conda recipe is not available. Just suggestions.

Comment: M1 can be difficult. Have you seen and followed posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72970797/8508004)?